# click event of each li tag

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am using the following code which li will have unique id.

```
<c:forEach var="food" varStatus="i" items="${selectedIngredientsList}">
        <c:set var="foodInfo" value="${food.foodItemId}~${food.foodCategoryId}~${food.foodName}~${food.foodPortionName}"/>    
        <ul id="my">
           <li id="my_${foodInfo}"><c:out value="${food.foodName}"/>
            </li>
        </ul> 
</c:forEach>
```

And I want to know on the click of each li, want to get the info ( foodInfo ) of the clicked li. How can I achieve it?

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my").bind(event,function(e){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```

Comment: Pro tip: don't use the id to store information. Take a look at [data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: imm.. I need to get the clicked data and need to send back to action class. That's why planning to do like that.

Comment: Yup, and putting that data to the id is really not the right way to do it.

Comment: thanks for the tip. this.html is better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will alert value inside each li and id  of li on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my li").click(function()
   {
        alert($(this).html());
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know the `id` of the clicked `li`, if that is correct then this should do what you want:

```
$("#my > li").on("click", function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a modified version of HarishAnchu

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my").on('click', 'li', function()
   {
        alert($(this).html());
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will work correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my").bind("click",function(e){
    alert("clicked");
  });
});
```